# PDFizer: how to inset picture in generated pdf document?

Tags: asp.net, pdf-generation

i'm using PDFizer library for .NET from here - [PDFizer](http://www.devtoolshed.com/content/c-free-component-generate-pdf-convert-html-pdf#comment-717)
and i need help... how i can convert all html document(including pictures stored in it) to PDF with this library? Now i can only generate pdf without images...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some testing, this is what you need to do:

- Create a Folder in which you will have all of your Images.
- If you already have an instance of `Pdfizer.HtmlToPdfConverter` change the `ImagePath` Attribute to point to the folder where your images reside.
- Include the `<img>` tags in your html code.
- Make sure the images are in the folder.

Note: I tried adding Png files and got a conversion error. Here is an example I took from the site you provided, plus my modifications:

```
System.Text.StringBuilder sbHtml = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
        sbHtml.Append("<html>");
        sbHtml.Append("<body>");
        sbHtml.Append("<font size='14'>My Document Title Line</font>");
        sbHtml.Append("<img src='trollface.jpg' />");
        sbHtml.Append("<br />");
        sbHtml.Append("This is my document text");
        sbHtml.Append("</body>");
        sbHtml.Append("</html>");




        //create file stream to PDF file to write to
        using (System.IO.Stream stream = new System.IO.FileStream

        (sPathToWritePdfTo, System.IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
        {
            // create new instance of Pdfizer
            Pdfizer.HtmlToPdfConverter htmlToPdf = new Pdfizer.HtmlToPdfConverter();
            // open stream to write Pdf to to
            htmlToPdf.Open(stream);
            htmlToPdf.ImagePath = Server.MapPath(ResolveUrl("~/Images"));

            // write the HTML to the component
            htmlToPdf.Run(sbHtml.ToString());
            // close the write operation and complete the PDF file
            htmlToPdf.Close();
        }
    }
```

Good luck!

Comment: No problem. If this helped you solve your issue please mark as answer.

Comment: i have another question to you...
for example i stored my picture in html code like - <img src='/Images/logo.png'> what i need to write in ImagePath? because i need all path like - http://site.com/images/logo.png

Comment: Remember what I told you about png images. They might or not work. In your html code you just write the filename of your image, the ImagePath property is supposed to have the full path where all the pictures are.

Comment: ok, thanks =) but in my case png pictures are working well :)

Comment: Good! There must have been something wrong with the image I tried. I am glad it is all working out. Have you been able to insert colored text into the pdf?